# Form that can select an image from a director on the site

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I was looking through the questions and I didn't see one that answered my question.  I am working on a pre-existing web site where the client wanted to be able to update his or her products.  I already have a directory filled with product images, so instead of just uploading and replacing the image, they can just select the image from the on-site directory.

- Is there a way to use the `file` input to search a directory that is on the site? ie: site.com/images
- Other than some possible security issues, which I will take care of, are there any onther potential problems with doing this?
- If i cannot do this with just html, is there a way to do it in javascript?

If there is another question that answers this, please don't leave hateful comments and down vote.  Post the link to said question in the comments and if it adequately answers my questions I will remove this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Is there a way to use the file input to search a directory that is on the site? ie: site.com/images"
No, this cannot be done.

You need to build a way for your users to be able to choose their image, either a simple select dropdown, or a more elaborateimage browser that would populate a hidden field in the form upon image selection (javascript involved)

Comment: I like this answer best so far and if my client wasn't on a small budget, I would seriously consider making an image browser.  I may do that as a side project.  That was a really good idea.

Comment: There might be a way to build something relatively fast... you could read the entire directory structure on the server and present it to the client with simple collapsible folders - clicking on a file would select it (assuming you don't have thousands of files)

Comment: I would say there are less than a hundred files, which I could cut down even further by putting all of the product images in a child directory and having only those images displayed in the finder.

Answer (score 2):

```
html file input help only in selecting client side file.
```

javascript in browser dosent allow  access to file system .you can ask the user to enter the file name to search and post to server and search for file and display output (here filename)by using some server side language.

Comment: I see, that is unfortunate.  I would rather not have the user enter , my client wants everything to be simple.

Comment: just list all file in your folder in a page ,then let user select using GUI.